# I keep receiving the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'" error message

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, flask, beautifulsoup

I am building a data scrapper for the website Basketball Reference, which pulls the headings and statistics from a given NBA player's Basketball Reference "Per Game" table and collects it to be displayed in a new page I am building and displaying.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    player_name = request.form['player']
    player_url = get_player_url(player_name)
    
    response = requests.get(player_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    stats = soup.find('div', {'id':'all_per_game'})
    
    table = stats.find('table')
    table_headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]
    table_data = []
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
      row_data = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all('td')]
      table_data.append(row_data)
      
    return render_template('stats.html', player_name=player_name, headings=table_headings, data=table_data)
  else:
    return render_template('index.html', players=players)
```

When I run the Python app in my localhost browser, I receive the following error message in response to collecting the table headings:

```
File ¨main.py¨, line 48, in index
   table_headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute find
```

I've looked around at other examples online and other queries on Stack, but I can't seem to find any solution that fits my case. Please mind I'm new to BeautifulSoup and this is my first time implementing it, so I'm not sure if my mistake is rudimentary or not. How would I be able to pull the headings, does it have something to do with the table objectType?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because at some point, may be at this line:  `table_headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]`, table returns None (i.e `NoneType`).

If table returns None, the next line will throw an error.

You can fix this by checking if table is not None before calling find.

So this:

```
table = stats.find('table')
    table_headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]
```

will change to

```
table = stats.find('table')
if table is not None:
    table_headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find('tr').find_all('th')]
```